# como acceder a un valor de una propiedad especifica de un objeto en js

Tags: javascript

tengo un objeto multidimensional en javascript al cual quiero acceder y obtener un valor de una propiedad especifica  pero al intentar obtener el valor me da error "Cannot read property 0 of undefined", cual es el error.

```
        var objeto2 = {
            nameKey: [{ nombre: "csrf_name", valor: "csrf5b91a8e01e786" }],
            valueKey: 
                [{
                    nombre: "csrf_value",
                    valor: "e70a02a75a53e5934af65685897e0d71"
                }]

        };

        var v1 = objeto2.namekey[0].valor;
        var v2 = objeto2.valueKey[0].valor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript es case sensitive. O sea que es una variable diferente con minusculas o mayusculas:

```js
var objeto2 = {
            nameKey: [{ nombre: "csrf_name", valor: "csrf5b91a8e01e786" }],
            valueKey: 
                [{
                    nombre: "csrf_value",
                    valor: "e70a02a75a53e5934af65685897e0d71"
                }]

        };

        var v1 = objeto2.nameKey[0].valor;
        var v2 = objeto2.valueKey[0].valor;
        console.log(v1);
        console.log(v2);
```

Comment: igual me sigue saliendo el error al acceder, ya que convierto un json del servidor.

Comment: este es el json que convierto con JSON.stringify()

Comment: "{\\"nameKey\\":[{\\"nombre\\":\\"csrf_name\\",\\"valor\\":\\"csrf5b91b1ac41a91\\"}],\\"valueKey\\":[{\\"nombre\\":\\"csrf_value\\",\\"valor\\":\\"c3a73a091c2de7d4ee122adce72b8fd9\\"}]}"'

Answer (score 0):

Solo quiero agregar que además se puede acceder a las propiedades de un objeto usando `[<string>]`, es útil cuando la propiedad está en una variable, por ejemplo cuando es dinámica o si estamos en un `for in` por ejemplo.

De cualquier manera siempre que se pueda es mejor acceder usando la notación de punto, como dice la respuesta de alanfcm, porque con solo verlo ya nos damos cuenta de la estructura del objeto:

```js
var objeto2 = {
            nameKey: [{ nombre: "csrf_name", valor: "csrf5b91a8e01e786" }],
            valueKey: 
                [{
                    nombre: "csrf_value",
                    valor: "e70a02a75a53e5934af65685897e0d71"
                }]

        };
                
        let clave1 = "nameKey";
        let clave3 = "valor"

        //alternativa a la notación de punto
        console.log(objeto2[clave1][0][clave3]);
        console.log(objeto2["valueKey"][0]["valor"]);
```